# Add a column to query output with the previous row column value in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Coulmns Present in table:

```
 id          toDate                                      
-----      ----------       
111          02-03-2017                                               

111          20-03-2017                                                

111          01-04-2017       

111          05-04-2017
```

Coulmns to be returned in query:

```
 id          toDate            fromDate                           
-----      ----------       ----------
111          02-03-2017        01-01-01  <---(always first record value)

111          20-03-2017        02-03-2017  <---(rest of the rows should be previous record's toDate value)                            

111          01-04-2017        20-03-2017

111          DatedNow          01-04-2017 <-- last record toDate should be current date
```

I have the query following query
`select id,toDate from myHistory order by toDate;`

Whats the query that need to be added for query to get the desired output?

Comment: In a database is no "previous row". The result is not sorted until you use order by

Answer (score 3):

you can do it with a query like this:

```
SELECT id,toDate,fromDate
FROM (
    SELECT m.*, @fromDate AS fromDate
    ,@fromDate := m.toDate
    FROM myHistory m
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @fromDate:='1901-01-01') AS init
    ORDER BY toDate
) AS result;
```

**sample**

```
mysql> SELECT id,toDate,fromDate
    -> FROM (
    ->     SELECT m.*, @fromDate AS fromDate
    ->     ,@fromDate := m.toDate
    ->     FROM myHistory m
    ->     CROSS JOIN (SELECT @fromDate:='1901-01-01') AS init
    ->     ORDER BY toDate
    -> ) AS result;
+-----+------------+------------+
| id  | toDate     | fromDate   |
+-----+------------+------------+
| 111 | 2017-03-02 | 1901-01-01 |
| 111 | 2017-03-20 | 2017-03-02 |
| 111 | 2017-04-01 | 2017-03-20 |
+-----+------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Hi Bernd Buffen, can you edit your answer as i have edited the question. Apologize for not adding the  DatedNow  value at the beginning. Thanks.